# Why am I getting zeros?

Tags: c, function, pointers, logic

I am trying to pass a function into another function that integrates, and I keep getting zeros. I'm not sure if it's the way I'm passing in the arguments, or if it's just a logic error in the math. Here are the functions.

```
double linear(double x){
  return x;
}

double quadratic(double x){
  return x*x;
}

double sinByX(double x){
  return sin(x)/x;
}

double rectangleIntegration(double a, double b, double n, double (*f)(double)){
  double integral = 0;
  double h = (b-a) / n;
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    integral = (f(a + (i * h))) * h;
  }
  return integral;
}

double trapazoidIntegration(double a, double b, double n, double (*f)(double)){
  double integral = 0;
  double h = (b-a) / n;
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    ((f(a+(i*h)) + f(a+((i+1)*h))) / 2) * h;
  }
  return integral;
}

double simpsonIntegration(double a, double b, double n, double (*f)(double)){
  double integral = 0;
  double h = (b-a) / n;
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    integral = (4*f((f(a+(i*h)) + f(a+((i+1)*h)))/2)) + f(a + (i*h)) + f(a + ((i + 1)*h));
  }
  return integral;
}
```

And here is where I call them...

```
double a = rectangleIntegration(2, 4, 2, linear(2));
  printf("%f\n", a);

  a = trapazoidIntegration(2, 4, 2, linear(2));
  printf("%f\n", a);

  a = simpsonIntegration(2, 4, 2, linear(2));
  printf("%f\n", a);
```

and it prints

```
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
```

Comment: What's your debugger show you?

Comment: Should not that be `integral += ...` instead of `integral = ...`? Besides, `trapazoidIntegration` does not modify `integral` at all. (Sarcasm hat on) @StarPilot - De... bug... ger? What's that?

Comment: In addition to the function pointer passing problem and the integral summing problem, I think your `simpsonIntegration` algorithm is incorrect. Better check that.

Comment: In trapezeoid... you never assign anything to integral, so it stays zero. The others take a function pointer argument, but you try to pass a double. Will that even compile?

Comment: To me the most interesting question here is how OP even managed to compile this. Apparently he did, given the "it prints" portion. I get the "cannot convert argument 4 from 'double' to 'double (__cdecl *)(double)" error with MSVC 2013.

Answer (score 1):

Passing a function argument like this

```
a = rectangleIntegration(2, 4, 2, linear(2));
```

should not take any arguments itself, it's just the name of the function, which is called from `rectangleIntegration()`. As stated, it does not compile.

The way you are calling it is as if you were passing the return value of `linear()`, not the function itself. Try it like this

```
a = rectangleIntegration(2, 4, 2, linear);
```

Answer (score 0):

try `rectangleIntegration(2, 4, 2, linear);`

Comment: I think you're on to something, but could you explain this a bit?

Comment: The fourth argument wants a function; `linear` is a function. `linear(2)` is a double--the result of calling the function `linear` and taking its return value.